# Does CUDA support 64 bit atomicSub()?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia

Im trying to use atomicAdds and atomicSubs on a piece of data, but i get a "no instance of overloaded function" error on the atomicSub but not the atomicAdd, I am using unsigned long long int as the data type on what i believe is a GeForce RTX 2060

The cuda programming guide mentions 64 bit element support for atomicAdd but not for atomicSub, so does this mean you can't do atomicSub with 64 bit numbers? If so, why would they support it for add but not sub?

Comment: You can implement your own atomicSub using atomicCAS

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned integers "over- or underflowing", e.g. `0u - 1u == UINT_MAX` is [not undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Overflows), like it is for signed integers. This is called modulo arithmetic, which means that every result is taken implicitly modulo the corresponding 2^`(sizeof(T) * 8)`. So instead of subtracting a number, you can just safely add the corresponding "inverse". In fact the unary minus operator is defined for `unsigned` and [gives the "right" result](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Unary_arithmetic_operators), which is **not** a negative, signed integer, but an appropriately big unsigned integer such that `uint_var + (-uint_var) == 0` is true.

This might also be the reason that `atomicSub` is not provided for many types. The CUDA architects might regret having put `atomicSub` into CUDA in the first place and the versions that are provided are probably only left in the API to not break old code.

This often unexpected modulo behavior is the reason why the C++ Core Guidelines are saying [not to use unsigned integers for arithmetic](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es102-use-signed-types-for-arithmetic), but [only for bit-manipulation](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es101-use-unsigned-types-for-bit-manipulation). In CUDA these guidelines are not easy to put into practice due to `threadIdx.x` and others being unsigned, but one should certainly know what one is doing when using `unsigned`.

#### TL;DR

You can just use `atomicAdd` with `-subtrahend` and should get the right result.